# Excel Power Query import (same file but with different month name)

Tags: powerquery

Each month I need to automate the importing of reference data, however the Excel file is named differently.

Monthly Data File January 2022.xlsx
Monthly Data File February 2022.xlsx

Could you point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In excel, use formulas ... name manager... to pick a cell and give it a range name, like **NameVariable**

Enter your filepath and filename **C:\temp\Monthly Data File January 2022.xlsx** in that named cell.  Change the content of that range as needed when filename changes later

Load one file into powerquery, then in home ... advanced editor ... add a formula that refers to that range name, similar to this:

```
MVar = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NameVariable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
```

and change any hard coded references to the filename to use **MVar** instead

As an example, change

```
let Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\temp\Monthly Data File January 2022.xlsx"), null, true),
```

to be

```
let MVar = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NameVariable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(MVar), null, true),
```

Comment: Hi there thank you for your prompt response.
I know how to get my data using Data, New Query, From File,From workbook but I am unsure how to access the Power Query as a stand alone. 

Or do I import the fist file and edit the source when I'm in Power Query?

Comment: Set up the range name and populate the cell.  Then import the first file into PQ using table ... from table/range.  Then edit the source in PQ using home...advanced editor...